# Remove Backward Rewinding Loop from Owl carousel

Tags: jquery, html, carousel, owl-carousel

I have created a simple slider with Owl carousel. In that slide contains total of 4 slides.

It works fine, but problem is after reaching 4 slide the carousel goes to 1st slide in backward rewinding.

I need a forward direction for all the slides in div data.

This is the settings which i have used,

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#testimonial-slider").owlCarousel({

        items:1,
        itemsDesktop:[1000,1],
        itemsDesktopSmall:[979,1],
        itemsTablet:[768,1],
        pagination:true,
        navigation:false,
        navigationText:["",""],
        slideSpeed:500,
        singleItem:true,
        autoPlay:true,
    });

});

</script>
```

[Demo Page](http://thepartners.co.in/#ClientSay)

Comment: why did you tag the question with `owl`?

Comment: i tried to give Owl carousel as tag, but suggestions showed me as owl and carousel are separated..

Comment: https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-options.html  loop:true in settings?

Comment: already tried with  loop:true.. not works

Comment: @DineshKumar when I enter `òwl` then `owl-carousel` will be suggested ...

Comment: tag updated.. :'(

Comment: I just can reccomend this: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/carousel.php Much more options, and i guess you can easily get desired result...

Comment: Thanks  sinisake .. i updated with new one.. now works good.. Thankyou!